# Arbitrary matrix or array size in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, matrix, simd, accelerate-framework

I am familiar with creating MxN matrices in Python using NumPy such as:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.zeros((10,5))
Out[2]:
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

In Swift, SIMD can create small matrices and perform operations on them (see below) but it appears to be limited to a max size of a 4x4 matrix.

```
import simd

let mat = float2x2([[1,2],[3,4]])
mat[0]*9
```

Is there a way to define an arbitrary sized matrix of MxN dimensions in Swift and perform operations on that matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "matrix", you mean an "array of arrays" then you can use the following syntax:

```
var matrix = Array(count: 10, repeatedValue: Array(count: 5, repeatedValue: 0.0))
```

This creates a 10 x 5 matrix of zeros.

Comment: That does create a MxN matrix but it doesn't allow for operations to be broadcast to the values within the matrix. In my example where I declared the matrix with SIMD, I could multiply it by 9; this operation doesn't work with an Array collection type.

Comment: Like I said, it creates an array of arrays, not a matrix in the mathematical sense. Similar to how you need NumPy to do it in Python, you need a similar scientific library in Swift. One that I found was [Swift Matrix Library](https://github.com/stsievert/swix). Seems to be inspired by NumPy too

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look at Swift Matrix. But why does SIMD only allow matrix dimensions up to 4x4?

Comment: @wigging , SIMD is designed for utilizing hardware SIMD functionality like 128-bit register containing 4 floats. Check [Accelerate framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/AccelerateFWRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009465) to find more general vector/array calculation.

Comment: @OOPer I'm not familiar with Accelerate. Does it provide it's own type for vectors and arrays or are you supposed to create them as Swift Arrays?

Comment: @wigging , no, most of the Accelerate subframeworks are just C-array based vector/matrix calculation packages.